# Tag _primaverabss_ VS _jasminsoftware_

Tags: debate

No site **SOpt** existem duas *tags* que são utilizadas para dúvidas de *software* da empresa **PRIMAVERA BSS**, que são [primaverabss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primaverabss) e [jasminsoftware](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasminsoftware).

Há algum tempo decidimos (colaboradores da empresa e maiores intervenientes nas questões dessas duas *tags*) juntar a *tag* [jasminsoftware](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasminsoftware) à [primaverabss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primaverabss) porque o *software* **Jasmin** é um produto da empresa, pelo que faria sentido estarem as duas "interligadas".

Recentemente concluimos que a *tag* [primaverabss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primaverabss) seria utilizada para o produto principal, um **ERP**, e a [jasminsoftware](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasminsoftware) seria utilizada, única e exclusivamente, para o produto **Jasmin**, separando assim os dois produtos.

Tendo em conta esta decisão removemos de todas as questões de **Jasmin** a *tag* [primaverabss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primaverabss), para separar os conceitos.

---

Colocámos esta questão aqui no Meta para explicar a qualquer um que se questione o porquê de não estarem as duas "juntas", ou porque anteriormente estavam e agora não.

Por outro lado, também dar a entender a novos utilizadores do *site* que em ambas as *tags* deva ser apenas colocado conteúdo técnico, associado à extensibilidade do produto e **não** questões funcionais (onde existe um fórum privado direcionado a isso).

Comment: Será interessante, então, adicionar as recomendações de uso às tags esclarecendo as diferenças.

Comment: Certo @AndersonCarlosWoss, acabei de o fazer :). Obrigado!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O que eu tenho percebido que a esmagadora maioria das perguntas feitas nessas *tags* são ruins. Quase sempre a pessoa pergunta o que fazer sem dar detalhes, sem mostrar esforço, em algumas casos nem sabemos se é de programação, em alguns casos não é mesmo, é só um pedido para fazer pra ele ou dar dicas de como proceder ou por falha da documentação ou porque a pessoa não quer consultá-la. A maioria delas parecem ser feitas por pessoas que nada entendem de programação, só de olhar a *tag* agora fechei todas que eu vi e negativei quase todas. Pra falar a verdade uma não só que a pergunta era sobre programação em geral e a *tag* estava lá circunstancialmente, nem deveria estar.

O pior é que muitas estão sem resposta ou tem respostas do tipo "este problema foi corrigido na nova versão". Parece que nem as pessoas que podem responder isso estão mais interessados no assunto.

Eu acho que sempre podemos testar coisas, mas a impressão que tenho que as perguntas dessas *tags* não estão funcionando bem por aqui e parece ter se tornando um problema. Não sei se outros consideram o mesmo e talvez fosse o caso até de discutir se elas estão no nosso tópico, já que só os fornecedores podem responder, e parecem que não estão mai estão interessados nisso, e o volume de problemas é muito maior que o benefício para os usuários, inclusive não está formando uma base de conhecimento que as pessoas vão achar aqui e será útil para a comunidade como um todo.

Queria ver mais opiniões.

Comment: Também tenho a mesma impressão sobre esta tag. Ela parece um suporte técnico do produto, que só a empresa e os clientes conseguem participar (posso estar enganado, mas é a impressão que me passa). De qualquer forma, acho que não tem como impedirmos que perguntas sobre o assunto sejam feitas (tem?), só nos resta ficar fechando mesmo...

Comment: Impedir não tem, mas pode-se discutir se as *tags* devem existir e padronizar um comportamento. Eu só não abri uma discussão específica porque acho que o meta não tem servido tanto pra balizar este tipo de coisa pela baixa participação, mas não descarto fazê-lo se ninguém fizer, porque se quase todo comportamento dentro de um padrão traz dificuldades para o site seria melhor tentar diminuir  (fechando, deixando claro que não é útil, quem sabe entendam), eu acho que isto tem trazido muito mais problema que [isto](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7893/101) que não teve muita aderência.

Comment: Note que eu nem cogito fechar qualquer coisa da *tag*, mas acho que seria interessante reduzir o nível de ruído da *tag* de alguma forma, não é bom alguma coisa que quase tudo mereça ser fechado, negativado, ou ambos.

Comment: Outra para a lista: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/404185/5878